# How to create a plist at WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to create a plist of the species, as it can be done on wp7?

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>
game
</key>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Check this](https://github.com/animetrics/PlistCS) C# Property List (plist) serialization library (MIT license).
It supports both XML and binary versions of the plist format.

To write a plist, e.g. dictionary

```
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"String Example", "Hello There"},
            {"Integer Example", 1234}
        };
        Plist.writeXml(dict, "xmlTarget.plist");
```

Comment: So, you didn't check the link ? Plist is a class, whose code is given in that link